# ODataQuery, React-Admin how to filter data by the array of objects nested in it

Tags: reactjs, odata, react-admin

React-Admin: version 2.9

I need OData to give me the results of the **id** that is in **assigness**.
Data example:

```
[
  0:{
     assigness:[
       {id: 77777, name: "dasdsadsa"},
       {id: 62321, name: "dasdsadsa"} 
     ],
     id: 3123123,
     other: "dsadasdsa"
  },
  1:{
     assigness:[
       {id: 42321, name: "dasdsadsa"},
       {id: 72321, name: "dasdsadsa"} 
     ],
     id: 4645,
     other: "dsadasdsa"
  },
]
```

Example i need object with **id** a value = 77777 and oData filter my array and return object with index 0

Comment: what have you tried? "any" function? $filter inside $expand? $top inside $expand? the query? I really dont know what exactly you trying to do, if you have the specific Id, you can filter by id, right? can you put more information about the expected response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this request helped me:
`assignees/any(b: b/id eq ${localStorage.getItem('id')})`

assignees - Array,
id - field this object